# pdo list top 5 using avg?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

Ok once again I am struggling making my movie rating system :(

My table structor is

```
      ID | UserID | Rating | TMDB |  TYPE
      -----------------------------------
       1      34        6     432      2
      -----------------------------------
       2      34        9     432      3
      -----------------------------------
       3      44        9     468      2
```

Thanks to user Barmar I was able to work out the average using

```
$sql = "SELECT AVG(rating) AS avg_rating FROM `tbl_rating` WHERE `tmdb`= :tmdb AND `type`= :type ";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':tmdb', $tmdb);
$stmt->bindParam(':type', $type);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$avg_rating = $row['avg_rating'];
```

Now I want to make a top 5 list of gorey horrors (type = 2). I have absolutely no clue how to work this out :( I know i can limit the results by a simple LIMIT command at the end and I think ORDER by AVG(rating) is need? and I need to drop the WHERE tmdb. I have no idea how to achive this could anyone help please!

Comment: if I use the avg on the colum it will add them all up instead i need to add them up in the tmdb group ID? I hope this makes scence to someone because my brain has turnt to mush

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your query to group by `tmdb` (instead of filter by), order the results by `avg_rating` (descending) and limit the rows returned to 5. Something like this:

```
SELECT `tmdb`, AVG(rating) AS avg_rating
FROM `tbl_rating`
WHERE `type`= :type
GROUP BY `tmdb`
ORDER BY avg_rating DESC
LIMIT 5
```

### Proof of concept:

You can run the following SQL commands in the MySQL console to validate the query returns sensible results on your sample data.

```
create table tbl_rating (
ID int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
UserID int unsigned,
Rating smallint unsigned,
tmdb int unsigned,
type int unsigned) engine=innodb;

insert into tbl_rating
(UserId, Rating, tmdb, `type`) values
(34, 6, 432, 2),
(34, 9, 432, 3),
(44, 9, 468, 2);

SELECT `tmdb`, AVG(rating) AS avg_rating
FROM `tbl_rating`
WHERE `type`= 2
GROUP BY `tmdb`
ORDER BY avg_rating DESC
LIMIT 5;

+------+------------+
| tmdb | avg_rating |
+------+------------+
|  468 |     9.0000 |
|  432 |     6.0000 |
+------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: that looks like what I need however for some reason im getting an error

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in C:\wamp\www\rating_results.php on line 39

Comment: and PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\wamp\www\rating_results.php on line 39

Comment: this is my sql: 
          $sql = "SELECT `tmdb`, AVG(rate) AS avg_rate FROM `tbl_rating` WHERE `type`= :type GROUP BY `tmdb` ORDER BY avg_rate DESC LIMIT 5";

Comment: Remove this line: `$stmt->bindParam(':tmdb', $tmdb)` because I removed the filter on `:tmdb` from the query.

Comment: Looks like the SQL in your comment has at least 1 typo. `AVG(rate)` should be `AVG(rating)` to match the column name in the table.

Comment: this does what i wanted, just wondering is there a way to make the list more fair? for example.... if someone votes tmdb23 gore as 10 it will show up as top even though it only has 1 vote? how hard would it be to implerment movie has a min amount of votes? or a different method for fairness?

Comment: Please post a new question for that. You can reference this question for context.